# Ajax call works in chrome/safari but fails in ff and ie

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox, compatibility

I'm using jQuery but the call just fails... It's nothing extraordinary... just a request with some base64 authorization header in the beforeSend

```
function GetProjects(full){
var query = "/Projects";
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url+query,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     beforeSend: function (req) {
        req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", AuthBuilder(username,password));
     },
     success: function (results) {
        $.each(results, function (i, item) {
            Projects[i] = item;
        });

        reloadui(full);
     },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {}
 });
}
```

this is sent over https to a service that is running at the same machine but I'm not using localhost anywhere. URL looks something like this: https://www.MYNAMEHERE.be:port/Route.

Everything works in chrome / safari, but it fails in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Thanks for reading

Edit: Setting the accepts header to JSON does not work either :) Tried to debug with Live HTTP Headers on FF but did not get any headers at all...

Comment: you are not sending JSON data but you have set content-type to `application/json` ?

Comment: that just a copy paste thingy ^^ you think that would make the difference? There are posts as well that don't work.. who DO send JSON; Edit: as expected doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add the **dataType: "json"** in the jquery ajax request. Now everything works just fine :)